# Having Trouble Inserting Row Into Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I've created a database, a table within that database, and now I'm having trouble inserting values into the table.

I've followed what the [documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_insert_query.htm) suggests for inserting a row. I'm trying to create a row of users:

```
Insert into users (column1, column2, column3)
values (user1, user2, user3);
```

And I'm getting this as an error:

```
university=# insert into users (column1, column2, column3)
university-# values (user1, user2, user3);
ERROR:  column "column1" of relation "users" does not exist
LINE 1: insert into users (column1, column2, column3)
```

I do know that I'm connected to the `university` database and there is in fact a `users` table.

[image]

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the actual names of the columns you have. Also note that the string values should be denoted by single quotes (`'`):

```sql
insert into users (id, name, password)
values (1, 'user1', 'password1')
```